# Flutter Flex() how to swap children position?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use `Flex()` widget to achieve different layout between screen orientations like below:

```
final _isPortrait = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait;

Flex(
  direction: _isPortrait ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(flex: _isPortrait ? 2 : 1, child: BottomButton1()),
    Expanded(flex: _isPortrait ? 1 : 0, child: BottomButton2()),
  ],
),
```

When orientation is portrait, of course the `BottomButton1()` will be on the left side as a first child.

However, when orientation is landscape, I want to swap the position of `BottomButton1()` and `BottomButton2()`, thus first child's position is now below of the second child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help you out

```
class _HelperState extends State<Helper> {
  RaisedButton button1 = RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Button 1'),
    onPressed: () {},
  );
  RaisedButton button2 = RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Button 2'),
    onPressed: () {},
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _isPortrait = false;
    print(_isPortrait);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Flex(
            direction: _isPortrait ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: _isPortrait ? 2 : 1,
                child: _isPortrait ? button1 : button2,
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: _isPortrait ? 1 : 0,
                child: _isPortrait ? button2 : button1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Obviously you need to substitute in your widgets let me know if you need anything else

Comment: this is what I anticipated, so is there really no other way? I wanted a prop like `reverseOrder` on the `Flex()` but looks like there's nothing like that ...

Comment: Not that I am away of as a part of flex some widgets have this property but they are listbuilders